# What does "fuller discussion" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

I am sorry for not being able to give you some context about this. I found this phrase from the "[Pearson Academic Words List](https://pearsonpte.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/AcademicCollocationList.pdf)". I tried a few dictionaries even, but still not able to understand the real meaning of this. Please give me the meaning and some example of the usage of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means a "longer and more detailed discussion". In this context a discussion is probably not a spoken conversation, but a piece of academic writing that considers multiple points of view.

> Programmers in C++ should avoid `using namespace std`.  For a fuller discussion of why this is the case, read the answers to [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)